# Format number Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, flow

Have been trying to convert a value shown as a percentage in a SharePoint list in Power Automate so that it displays correctly in an email.

Originally the number (50%) although displaying correctly in the list was then coming out via Power Automate email as 0.500000000000000.

I therefore added initialize variable and used that value as an output using the expression:

```
formatNumber(float(triggerBody()?['Non_x0020_Conf_x0020__x0025_']), '0.00')
```

It is now coming out as 0.50.

I just want it showing as 50 – any ideas? I can see that the 0.00 is probably defining it but tried changing it to just 0 and then the value was 1. So any suggestions for correct syntax welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this expression:

```
formatNumber(mul(float(triggerBody()?['Non_x0020_Conf_x0020__x0025_']), 100), '0.00')
```

It will multiply the float number by 100 and then format it with two digits after decimal point.